# Getting the Timing of a Specific Part of Code in a Loop in C

Tags: c, time, do-while, clock, time.h

## Description of Problem

Below I have a program that is performing two simple addition and multiplication operations. I am then storing the sum of these two simple operations in two respective variables called total1 and total2. In terms of computation total2 will take more time to be fully executed. The way I implemented the code, I am currently timing the entire simulation of both mathematical operations.

## Question

Is it possible to time solely the end result of total1 and total 2 separately? I am asking so as I wish to get the specific time of total1 and total2 in a separate manner.

## Purpose of Task

I am fully aware that long long is expensive with regards to memory and is not the most efficient way to save up memory. The sole purpose of this code and question is timing and not code optimization.

## C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

     long long total1 = 0, total2 = 0, i = 0;
     double simulation_time = 0;

     clock_t Start = clock();

     do
     {
          total1 += i + i; 
          total2 += i * i * i * i; 

          i++;

     } while (i < 1000000000);

     clock_t End = clock();

     printf("Total 1 = %u \n", total1);
     printf("Total 2 = %u \n", total2);

     simulation_time = (double)(End - Start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     printf("Runtime of Whole Simulation using clock_t: %f\n", simulation_time);


     return 0;
}
```

Comment: When looking at this in Visual Studio the debugger tells me that all the variables has been optimized away, so take *no memory*. Only registers. The code for `total1 += i + i;` becomes a single op `lea         rdi,[rdi+rbx*2] ` which Intel's manuals can tell you takes a fraction of a nanosecond on a PC. Do you *really* need to measure this more closely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem, but to time each operation separately you simply have to make two separate loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    long long total1 = 0, total2 = 0, i = 0, j = 1000000000;
    double simulation_time1, simulation_time2;
    clock_t Start, End;

    /* addition */
    Start = clock();
    do
    {
         total1 += i + i;
         i++;
    } while (i < j);
    End = clock();
    simulation_time1 = (double)(End - Start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    /* multiplication */
    Start = clock();
    do
    {
         total2 += i * i * i * i;
         i++;
    } while (i < j);
    End = clock();
    simulation_time2 = (double)(End - Start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Total 1 = %u \n", total1);
    printf("Total 2 = %u \n", total2);
    printf("Runtime of Whole Simulation: %f\n"
        "Runtime of Addition:         %f\n"
        "Runtime of Multiplication:   %f\n",
        simulation_time1 + simulation_time2,
        simulation_time1, simulation_time2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A problem here is that (after adding `i = 0` before the second loop) I get `Addition 0.23` and `Multiplication 0.68`. But in the original code I get `0.68` in total. So what are we measuring? Hint: On a PC with multiple execution units an add and a mul could possibly execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You have two operations you wish to time separately.  The first is accumulation of `i+i`, and the second is accumulation of `i*i*i*i`.

I am going to assume you are using GCC on x86-64 with `-O2`.

If we comment out `total2`, the generated assembly for the calculation of `total1` is:

```
  movabs rdx, 999999999000000000
```

Clever compiler!  It does the entire computation at compile time.  So the time taken by that is basically zero.

If we instead comment out `total1`, the assembly for the loop to calculate `total2` is:

```
.L2:
  mov rdx, rax
  imul rdx, rax       ; i squared
  add rax, 1
  imul rdx, rdx       ; i squared squared
  add rsi, rdx        ; accumulate
  cmp rax, 1000000000 ; loop condition
  jne .L2
```

Rather than trying to microbenchmark single lines of code, we can consult Agner Fog's instruction tables: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Assuming you're using Intel Haswell, and doing a little port allocation by hand, the tables tell us:

```
.L2:                  ; ports  cycles  latency
  mov rdx, rax        ; p0     0.25    1
  imul rdx, rax       ; p1     1       3
  add rax, 1          ; p0     0.25    1
  imul rdx, rdx       ; p1     1       3
  add rsi, rdx        ; p0     0.25    1
  cmp rax, 1000000000 ; p5     0.25    1
  jne .L2             ; p6     1-2
```

Some of those instructions can overlap, so this should be roughly 3-4 core cycles per iteration.  On a 3-4 GHz processor, it will take about 1 second to do one billion iterations of the loop.